# How to elevate Maven source compiler version to JDK 7

Tags: java, maven

Having this build error

```
error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
```

I want to elevate the source compiler version to 1.7 how to do that in eclipse?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-compile-maven-project-with-different-jdk-version/

Answer (score 1):

In your `pom.xml` look for the blurb

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.5</source>
        <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and change accordingly.

Cheers,